Convexity of this "quadratic" form
I have the following "quadratic" form
$$
\operatorname{E}\left(\operatorname{f}\right) =
\nabla\left(\operatorname{f}\right)^T J\nabla\left(\operatorname{f}\right)
$$
where J is a positive semi-definite $2 \times 2$ matrix and $\operatorname{f}:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I want to show that it is convex with respect to $\operatorname{f}$.
My initial idea was to simply apply the ( inequality ) definition of convexity, but I guess there is a more clever and faster way by looking at the Hessian of this form with respect to $\operatorname{f}$, but I don't know how to properly compute it.

